# Unmanaged Extension TransactionEventHandler Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, jax-rs

This is also on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/neo4j

I'm trying to create an unmanaged extension which puts a message on a queue when a node becomes interesting (e.g. a relationship of a new type is created)

I believe I can do this with a TransactionEventHandler so I have created a class which extends KernelExtensionFactory which has a method (newKernelExtension) which returns a LifeCycle. My LIfeCycleAdapter then registers the TransactionEventHandler in the start method. In my class that implements TransactionEventHandler i have afterCommit, which basically just writes to a text file for the sake of testing.

In conf/neo4j-server.properties I have put the following -

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.extensions.events=/db/events
```

However the server doesnt start. in console.log I get this -

```
21:10:57.446 [main] WARN  /db/events - unavailable
   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) ~[jersey-server-1.9.j
```

Now, in my code I haven't declared any paths as I don't need a REST interface to this, I just want it to start when the server starts and then listen for transaction events and then do something with the transaction data (e.g. write to a file or a messaging queue)

So my question is -

Do I need to declare a path? Does an unmanaged extension have to be a jaxrs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a server extension but just a kernel extension,

so you ***don't need this config****, which is only for server/REST-extensions:

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.extensions.events=/db/events
```

Just put your jar in the `plugins` directory and make sure your have the correct META-INF/services/org.neo4j....KernelExtension file packed in the jar with the fully qualified name of your class as content

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I've put my code here -http://pastebin.com/1KtFeZ4L I have /META-INF/services/org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensionFactory in my source folder, with "org.neo4j.extensions.events.NeoEvents" in it. (bad namespacing convention I know, was just hacking about). I'd using the eclipse export as jar (I'm no eclipse expert).

Comment: Make sure with `jar -tvf xxxextension.jar` that the META-INF/services/... is really in the JAR?

Comment: So it looks about right. I've posted it here - http://pastebin.com/fTAQ2sYZ. Is the filename org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensionFactory correct? I've set logging to the finest and see no sign of my plugin in either console.log or neo*.log in the log directory.

Comment: Figured it out in the end. I needed to more the META-INF directory and also I had an Eclipse issue where I believed I had set the compiler to 1.6 but actually it was still at 1.5.

Comment: Could you tip me off on this one? Run into the same problem but I didn't figure out how you made it

Comment: For 4.1 you can check here https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-transaction-event-listener-extension